# Delete and Update dynamically created Table row ID's serially using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

For example I am listing products for sale using ajax, jquery on Table. Where every table row are getting dynamic id's like, row_1, row_2, row_3 etc.

There is an option to remove any of rows, for example second row(row_2) is removed.

So what I want is, after the row gets deleted, the table row id's should get update also, probably a function will do it, for example I don't want it to be row_1, row_3 instead I want it to be row_1, row_2.

Comment: And how does your code look like ? Will you mind sharing that ? A static `JSON/Array` could be used instead of `AJAX` request..

Comment: No I needed Ajax for other purpose..Anyways, other answers help me sort it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd this code already with me somewhere in my project, tweaked little but as per your need.

**Jquery part**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".remove_tr").click(function(){

        var tr_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");

        var flag = "N"; var row_cnt = 0;

        $("#dummy_table tr").each(function(){

            if( flag == "Y" ){ 

                $(this).attr("id", "row_"+ row_cnt); 
                $(this).children("td:first-child").html("row_"+ row_cnt); 
                $(this).attr("id", "row_"+ row_cnt); 
                row_cnt++; 
            }

            if( flag =="N" && $(this).attr("id") == tr_id){ 

                var rowArr = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
                row_cnt = rowArr[1]; 

                $(this).remove(); flag= "Y";  
            }                                        
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML part**

```
<table id="dummy_table">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){ ?>        
        <tr id="row_<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <td>row_<?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td class="remove_tr">remove</td>
        </tr> 
    <?php } ?>        
</table>
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for...Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Run code snippet below.

```js
$(".remove").click(function() {
  
  $(this).parent().remove();
  
  var counter = 1;
  $("#foo tr").each(function() {

    $(this).attr('id', 'row_'+counter);
    $(this).find('td:first-child').html('row_'+counter);  //just to show the result     
    counter++;
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="foo">
          
  <tr id="row_1" class="block" >
    <td>row_1</td>
    <td class="remove">remove</td>
  </tr> <br>
  
  <tr id="row_2" class="block" >
    <td>row_2</td>
    <td class="remove">remove</td>
  </tr> <br> 
  
  <tr id="row_3" class="block" >
    <td>row_3</td>
    <td class="remove">remove</td>
  </tr> <br>
  
  <tr id="row_4" class="block" >
    <td>row_4</td>
    <td class="remove">remove</td>
  </tr> <br>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Yes your code worked fine..Thank you..appreciate your help :)